# Get new data when paging dates

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to grab a new chunk of data via an Ajax call whenever the user switches date ranges-- IE, clicks Next Day button, switches modes, etc.

I think I should use viewDisplay(view), but that seems like it's too late-- the data has already been loaded?

Should I use viewDisplay(view) and do an ajax call and set-- something?  Or should I be looking at a different "event" in the calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Direct qutoe form the documentation

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>       events: '/myfeed.php' }); Here is a URL that FullCalendar might visit:
>
> /myfeed.php?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646
>
> The _ parameter is automatically
>   inserted to prevent the browser from
>   caching the result

You should have a page that accepts this parameter- queries your DB, gets an array/table back in the format of event object

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Then serialize that to a JSON using a library, remember to format time in ISO8601 !! AND fullcalendar request time using UNIX Timestamps...

Goodluck

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try that, though I was hoping to do it a bit more manually. It is a .Net page, so there is already a WebMethod defined that is in use. I was hoping to just be able to catch the date page, call the Page Method(start, end), get the JSON that page method returns, and update the calendar manually.